# How to replace Bash with Xonsh

Tags: shell, linux-mint, xonsh

I am using Linux Mint 19.1

I want to use Xonsh as my default shell.

According to their [documentation](https://xon.sh/linux.html), The latest version of Xonsh can only be installed using conda, pip, or from source.

conda:

```
$ conda config --add channels conda-forge
$ conda install xonsh
```

pip:

```
$ pip install xonsh
```

source: Download the source from github ([zip file](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/archive/master.zip)), then run the following from the source directory,

```
$ python setup.py install
```

I am not sure if installing a shell with pip will allow it to make it default.

Moreover, In a [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/change-a-users-default-shell-in-linux/), I found that we can use `usermod` to change user’s login shell and `chsh` to change login shell. I am not sure which is what. And what is the correct way to make a shell absolutely default (as if bash even does not exist).

Comment: "we can use usermod to change user’s login shell and chsh to change login shell": only `chsh` could be used by a non-priveleged user to change her *own* shell (provided that it's in `/etc/shells`). only `chsh` is a setuid program; `usermod` can only be used by root &co.

Comment: I’m (somewhat reluctantly) voting to reopen this because “How do I change *my* login shell?” seems to be a valid question.  We have several questions that say “I’m using `chsh` and it’s not working; Help!”, but I can’t find any where the *answer* is simply “Use `chsh`.”

Comment: I asked the question on their GitHub page. We have to first check that xonsh is on the $PATH. Then, as root, add xonsh to the shell list. Only then run `$ chsh -s $(which xonsh)`. https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/3153#issuecomment-499211722